# "Incorrect link" in episerver 7 when doing project as MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, episerver-7

I've just created a new EpiServer 7 MVC project and created my first pagetype and page, the start page. In admin mode I can see the start page and if I single step in the start page controller I can see that "currentPage" has values.

BUT if I go to the page in the normal mode (not in edit in admin) I just get the "Incorrect link". If I single step I also see that "currentPage" is null in the controller. I thinks it's weird that EpiServer succeds in calling the right controller and action and then not being able to render it (it finds the view as well). I have no clue what's going on. I can't see any differences from how I've set up previous sites that works.

The exception is

```
Exception details: 

HttpException: Not Found
Http status: 

404 NotFound
```

If I create a project with webforms (no MVC) it works but it is when I merge a MVC project into the EPI-project this happens.

I have no clue what's wrong so thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a new mvc site. After bending my brain for a couple of hours I found that although I had created a start page, I hadn't **published** it. After publishing the problem disappeared. Oh my...